# Issue with using Generic Type in interface

Tags: android, types, type-conversion

I'm trying to make a base helper class to entertain all api calls of my app, so i have wrote it as following code but issue is that when i call it gives warning "Unchecked call to onResponse(T) as a member of Raw Type" at line '   taskListener.onResponse(response);' . I know that i'm not passing type to ApiTaskListener  in executeApiCall method, but if i use 'ApiTaskListener' then it shows error at the 'taskListener.onResponse(response);' line and asks to remove Generic Type from ApiTaskListener interface and use Type as Object. I don't want to use Object because of casting overhead everytime in my calling method.
Any suggestions would be appreciable.

calling method:

```
makeApiCall(request, new ApiTaskListener<PeopleResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(PeopleResponse response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ApiError apiError) {

            }
        });
```

Base class code:

```
protected void makeApiCall(Single<?> request, ApiTaskListener<?> taskListener) {

        if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(getResourceProvider().getContext())) {
            if (taskListener != null)
                taskListener.onError(new ApiError(410, getResourceProvider().getString(R.string.internet_error)));
            return;
        }

        getCurrentUserSession(new SessionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                executeApiCall(request, taskListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ApiError error) {
                if (taskListener != null)
                    taskListener.onError(error);
            }
        });

    }

    private void executeApiCall(Single<?> request, ApiTaskListener taskListener) {
        getCompositeDisposable().add(request
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe((Consumer<Object>) response -> {
                    if (taskListener != null)
                        taskListener.onResponse(response);
                }, throwable -> {
                    if (taskListener != null)
                        taskListener.onError(AppApiHelper.parseApiError(throwable));
                }));
    }


    public interface ApiTaskListener<T>{
        void onResponse(T response);

        void onError(ApiError apiError);
    }
```

Comment: when using this `<?>` (unknown type) wildcard this has an upper and lower bound of `Object`, so at runtime it can only be an `Object` - your base class should be declared something like `BaseClass<T>` where `T` is your response type, or type params on your methods.

Comment: I don't want to declare Type with my BaseClass because in the child class i might be calling apiCall multiple times and response type could be different for them

Comment: "or type params on your methods" - quoting myself, I'm sure that this covers that ...

Comment: could you please share a code snippet as i didn't understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (replacing the wildcard `<?>` for `<T>`):

```
protected <T> void makeApiCall(Single<T> request, ApiTaskListener<T> taskListener) {

    if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(getResourceProvider().getContext())) {
        if (taskListener != null)
            taskListener.onError(new ApiError(410, getResourceProvider().getString(R.string.internet_error)));
        return;
    }

    getCurrentUserSession(new SessionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            executeApiCall(request, taskListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(ApiError error) {
            if (taskListener != null)
                taskListener.onError(error);
        }
    });

}

private <T> void executeApiCall(Single<T> request, ApiTaskListener<T> taskListener) {
    getCompositeDisposable().add(request
            .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
            .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
            .subscribe((Consumer<T>) response -> {
                if (taskListener != null)
                    taskListener.onResponse(response);
            }, throwable -> {
                if (taskListener != null)
                    taskListener.onError(AppApiHelper.parseApiError(throwable));
            }));
}


public interface ApiTaskListener<T>{
    void onResponse(T response);

    void onError(ApiError apiError);
}
```

Although I would recommend that you rework all your current callbacks (`ApiTaskListener` could be removed and change/overload `getCurrentUserSession` as a blocking call) then you could just return a `Single<T>` and subscribe to that rather than wrapping it in a callback.  I don't know enough about the other code to really provide a decent base for that.

Comment: It says  "makeApiCall
(io.reactivex.Single<T>,
utils.interfaces.ApiTaskListener<T>)
in BaseApiHelperViewModel cannot be applied
to
(io.reactivex.Single<capture<?>>,
anonymous utils.interfaces.ApiTaskListener<java.lang.Object>)
 "